# Null Object Reference error on programmatically created checkboxes

Tags: android, null, findviewbyid

I have a program that creates check boxes programmatically based on user inputs in the activities prior. while the check boxes are made properly, when it comes time to see if they are checked I get an Null Object Reference Error. I am very aware that there are similar threads however all of them contain very specific answers, and none that solve my issue.

```
 //this part is in the OnCreate portion of the activity   
String [] winQuest;
        winQuest = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.windowQuestions);


        for (int i = 0; i < winQuest.length; i++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            //row.setId(i);
            row.setLayoutParams(basicParams);

            TextView questionText = new TextView(this);
            questionText.setText(winQuest[i]);
            questionText.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.black));
            questionText.setId(R.id.questionText + i);
            row.addView(questionText);

            TableRow row2 = new TableRow(this);
            //row2.setId(i);
            row2.setLayoutParams(basicParams);

            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
            String boxId = i + "1000";
            int id = Integer.parseInt(boxId);
            checkBox.setId(id);
            checkBox.setText(simpleAns[0]);
            row2.addView(checkBox);
            //subChecks.add(checkBox);

            TableRow row3 = new TableRow(this);
            //row3.setId(i);
            row3.setLayoutParams(basicParams);

            CheckBox checkBox2 = new CheckBox(this);
            String boxId2 = i + "2000";
            int id2 = Integer.parseInt(boxId2);
            checkBox.setId(id2);
            checkBox2.setText(simpleAns[1]);
            row3.addView(checkBox2);
            //subChecks.add(checkBox2);

            TableRow row4 = new TableRow(this);
            //row4.setId(i);
            row4.setLayoutParams(basicParams);

            CheckBox checkBox3 = new CheckBox(this);
            String boxId3 = i + "3000";
            int id3 = Integer.parseInt(boxId3);
            checkBox.setId(id3);
            checkBox3.setText(simpleAns[2]);
            row4.addView(checkBox3);
            //subChecks.add(checkBox3);

            TableRow row5 = new TableRow(this);
            //row5.setId(i);
            row5.setLayoutParams(basicParams);

            EditText addtlNotesText = new EditText(this);
            addtlNotesText.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.notes));
            String textId4 = i + "4000";
            int id4 = Integer.parseInt(textId4);
            checkBox.setId(id4);
            row5.addView(addtlNotesText);
            noteText.add(addtlNotesText);

            rootLayout.addView(row);
            rootLayout.addView(row2);
            rootLayout.addView(row3);
            rootLayout.addView(row4);
            rootLayout.addView(row5);

        }


    //this part happens OnClick
    String [] winQuest;
                winQuest = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.windowQuestions);

                for(int i = 0; i < winQuest.length; i++){

                    fieldNoteResponses = "";

                    String subCheck = i + "1000";
                    String subCheck2 = i + "2000";
                    String subCheck3 = i + "3000";

                    int box = Integer.parseInt(subCheck);
                    final CheckBox subChecked1 = findViewById(box);

                    int box2 = Integer.parseInt(subCheck2);
                    final CheckBox subChecked2 = findViewById(box2);

                    int box3 = Integer.parseInt(subCheck3);
                    final CheckBox subChecked3 = findViewById(box3);

                        if (subChecked1.isChecked()) {
                            fieldNoteResponses = "Yes";
                        }

                        if (subChecked2.isChecked()){
                            fieldNoteResponses = "No";
                        }

                        if (subChecked3.isChecked()) {
                            fieldNoteResponses = "Not Applicable";
                        }

                    String addNotes = "";

                    String textCheck = i + "4000";
                    int textId = Integer.parseInt(textCheck);
                    final EditText addText = findViewById(textId);

                    addNotes = addText.getText().toString();
    }
```

When running this code I get a null object reference on the "if (subChecked1.isChecked())" part of the code.

For reference here is the error:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: redcaribou.abbphotoorganizerv2, PID: 4942
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference
                  at redcaribou.abbphotoorganizerv2.FirstCheckList.onClick(FirstCheckList.java:394)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5623)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6314)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `findViewById(box)` and other findViewById() method calls. You need to provide an xml element id here; like `findViewById(R.id.checkBox1)`. It actually resolves to an `int` value. I suggest you do some reading around findViewById().